# Edit Chrome manifest

Tags: google-chrome, manifest

Time ago I did a theme for Chrome using a web engine if I'm not mistaken.

It always worked till Chrome upgraded to version 23. Now when I want to install the theme I get this error:

Could not load extension from '/extension_path/'. The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details.

I guess I have to open the manifest.json and edit the key value to 2? I really don't know, never worked with it. How can I open the manifest?

If I have the extension installed and update to 23, it keeps working without any problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out Chrome's documentation on [Manifest Version](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html). Find the `manifest.json` file in the extension's folder and add

```
"manifest_version": 2,
```

in there.

Comment: They're no longer supporting manifest v1. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#manifest-v1-support-schedule and the section below it (Changes between version 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you test after adding the manifest key to the manifest.json. Your Extension might not work properly. Mine didn't.